# mysql select date from DB where NOW() between t1.from and t1.to with t1.to not defined

Tags: mysql

I have a table (t1) with:

```
id  |    from              |      to               |   item   |   price   |
1      2014-03-14 00:00:00    2014-03-26  00:00:00      25         75
2      2014-03-27 00:00:00       NULL                   25         50
3      2014-03-27 00:00:00    2014-04-01  00:00:00      26         80 
4      2014-04-02 00:00:00       NULL                   26         100
```

Now in case of `item = 25` I'd like to select `t1.id = 2`. In this case the date is betwwen `2014-03-27` and NULL because it is not know when this price will end.

In case of `item = 26` I'd like to get `t1.id = 3` until the 1st of April and the starting from the 2nd of April `t1.id = 4`.

How should I write my query?

**EDIT:**

Idea for query:

```
SELECT `from`, IF(`to` IS NOT NULL, `to`, NOW()), price, item
  FROM t1
WHERE NOW() BETWEEN `from` 
            AND IF(`to` IS NOT NULL,
                   `to`,
                   NOW()
                )
ORDER BY item
```

Expected results today (31st of March):

```
id  |    from              |      to               |   item   |   price   |
2      2014-03-27 00:00:00       NULL                   25         50
3      2014-03-27 00:00:00    2014-04-01  00:00:00      26         80
```

Expected results on the 3rd of April:

```
id  |    from              |      to               |   item   |   price   |
2      2014-03-27 00:00:00       NULL                   25         50
4      2014-04-02 00:00:00       NULL                   26         100
```

Comment: Can you also add expected result set in tabular format.

Comment: Updated my question also with idea for query

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer or at least vote ...

Answer (score 0):

You can just include column `to` and avoid `if` expression in the select statement.

```
SELECT 
  id, `from`, `to`, price, item
FROM t1
WHERE NOW() BETWEEN 
            `from` AND IF(`to` IS NOT NULL, `to`, NOW() )
ORDER BY item;
```

And for any future target date records,

```
set @future_date := now() + interval 3 day;

SELECT 
  id, `from`, `to`, price, item, @future_date
FROM t1
WHERE @future_date BETWEEN `from`
                   AND IF(`to` IS NOT NULL, `to`, @future_date )
ORDER BY item;
```

**Demo** @ [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b10b8e/4)

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works

```
SELECT `from`, `to`, item, price
    FROM t1
    WHERE NOW() BETWEEN `from` AND `to`
    OR `from` <= NOW() AND ISNULL(`to`)
    ORDER BY item;
```

And to proof that it works in the future here's another query for 3rd of April

```
SELECT `from`, `to`, item, price
    FROM t1
    WHERE '2014-04-03' BETWEEN `from` AND `to`
    OR `from` <= '2014-04-03' AND ISNULL(`to`)
    ORDER BY item;
```

Here's my **[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca702/1)**

Everything's clear?